# PNPM build and publish TypeScript monorepo

Tags: typescript, monorepo, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

I have a TypeScript monorepo with PNPM. There are two projects in `packages`: `app` and `lib`.

`app` depends on `lib` with PNPM workspace feature. The `package.json` file of `app` looks like below, as well as the build script.

```json
{
  // ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@shaunxu/lib": "workspace:^"
  }
}
```

Now I would like to build `app` and `lib` into JS to the folder `dist/app` and `dist/lib` so that it can be published to NPM registry. If I run `pnpm -r build` it will compile my TypeScript into JavaScript but the `dependencies` part of `package.json` was NOT translated. If I run `pnpm -r publish` the `dependencies` part was changed correctly but it pack my TypeScript file.

How can I combine the build (compile) and publish (or `dependencies` translate) process.

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally figured out this issue. Basically it seems impossible to publish packages from a root-level `dist` folder because it out of the workspace range.

What we need to do is to build each package into its own `dist` folder. For instance we need to build `packages/lib` into `packages/lib/dist` and `packages/app` into `packages/app/dist`. We also need to copy `package.json` into `dist` as well.

Then add `publishConfig.directory` section in each `package.json` as below, indicates to pack the files under `dist` folder.

```json
{
  // ...
  "publishConfig": {
    "directory": "dist"
  }
}
```

Now we can use `pnpm -r publish` to pack and publish each packages with the workspace part translated.